# Media Recorder shims/polyfills available for Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, mediarecorder

I'm building an application in React in which I need to record the users' webcam video and audio. Thus far it works in Chrome and Firefox (as expected), but I'm currently trying to find a fallback or a polyfill for Edge and Safari, since I want to be able to support those browsers as well.

Have any been made available? I have not been able to find any information whatsoever in regards to this.

Comment: I've not found anything useful either, I thought there might be a flash fallback or *something*

Comment: Yeah, I've given up trying to find a solution and went with an Electron application for Edge and Safari users.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's an interesting approach I hadn't considered.